# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll when trying to load xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am simply trying to load an XML file and keep getting this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Here is my code... pretty simple

```
            string thirdParty = @"\3rdParty\";
            string path = @"C:\code\depot\LALA\LALA";
            string pathToXML = @"C:\code\";
            List<string> thirdPartyPaths = new List<string>();
            string[] xmlPaths = Directory.GetFiles(pathToXML, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string element in xmlPaths)
            {
                if (element.Contains("input.xml"))
                {
                    pathToXML = element;
                }
            }

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(pathToXML);
```

#### input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<ism_node>
   <product name="SomeName">
      <td>Client.ism</td>
      <td>Server64.ism</td>
      <td>Database.ism</td>
      <td>AdminConsole.ism</td>
   </product>
   <product name="Backward Compatibilty Pack">
      <td>ClientLibraryUpdate.ism</td>
   </product>   
   <product name="Mobile SDK">
      <td>MobileSDK.Installer.ism</td>
   </product>
   <product name="Snap">
      <td>AdminConsole.Installer.ism</td>
      <td>Client.Installer.ism</td>
   </product>
</ism_node>
<module_node>
    <module name="Standard Export">
        <project>Stdexp.csproj</project>
    </module>
    <module name="">
        <project></project>
    </module>
</module_node>
```

After debugging I have confirmed that I am definitely referencing a full XML path when trying to load. I have no idea how to fix this and have looked for hours on SO to find something!

Comment: UNless you have some permission problem on the source path, it seems that the error comes out when you try to _xmldoc.Load_ so perhaps the problem is in the XML content that you try to read. Can you post that file content? Also note that if you have more than one file named, also partially,  with the string _input.xml_ you read only the last file in your array

Comment: `XDocument` is the new `XmlDocument`. Unless there are `XmlDocument` specific things you want to do with `XmlDocument`, you really should prefer `XDocument` instead.

Comment: And like @Steve said your "pathToXml" variable will always contains only the last value of the "xmlPaths" array. Even worse if your folder don't contains any files ending with .xml you will throw an exception since you try to load from a folder path.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the quick response. I have edited my question with the XML document that I am trying to load. I have also verified that the string with the file path is the one I am definitely trying to load.

Comment: @spender I am simply trying to access data from XML nodes. Does XDocument grant the same privileges?

Comment: @jshaf The API for XDocument is considerably easier to use than that of XmlDocument and gives you the lovely Linq-to-XML If you're looking for the (2016) idiomatic way of pulling data out of an XML document, XDocument is the one for you.

Comment: That XML file is invalid.

Comment: However this should not give that error. Please check if you have any kind of permission problem in reading files in the pathToXML

Comment: @spender okay I'll take your word for it and implement that.

Comment: That file looks like a bunch of XML fragments. XML does not allow multiple root nodes ( `<ism_node>` and `<module_node>`)

Comment: @Steve why is the XML invalid?

Comment: @spender ahh so if I wrap it all in one root node it would suffice?

Comment: Multiple root elements

Comment: @jshaf It would make a valid document. I can't say if your cryptic error message is related, but you should definitely fix your source data before jumping to any conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed the root node for the XML document. I had more than one root node and that throws this error. my new xml doc looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<input>
<ism_node>
   <product name="SomeName">
      <td>Client.ism</td>
      <td>Server64.ism</td>
      <td>Database.ism</td>
      <td>AdminConsole.ism</td>
   </product>
   <product name="Backward Compatibilty Pack">
      <td>ClientLibraryUpdate.ism</td>
   </product>   
   <product name="Mobile SDK">
      <td>MobileSDK.Installer.ism</td>
   </product>
   <product name="Snap">
      <td>AdminConsole.Installer.ism</td>
      <td>Client.Installer.ism</td>
   </product>
</ism_node>
<module_node>
    <module name="Standard Export">
        <project>Stdexp.csproj</project>
    </module>
    <module name="">
        <project></project>
    </module>
</module_node>
</input>
```

Comment: Multiple root elements is throwing a System.XmlException : 'There are multiple root elements' not a 'System.AccessViolationException'